# Разделение элементов горизонтального меню

Tags: меню, html

Вообщем есть 4 элемента которые нужно разместить горизонтально, для этого я составил таблицу. (мб есть другие способы, но я новичек..)

```
<table><!--Таблица-->
      <tbody><!--Тело таблицы-->
       <tr><!--Начало строки-->
         <td><!--Начало первого столбца-->

         </td> <!--Конец первого столбца-->
         <td>  <!--Начало второго столбца-->

         </td> <!--Конец второго столбца-->
         <td> <!--Начало третьего столбца-->

         </td> <!--Конец третьего столбца-->
         <td><!--Начало четвертого столбца-->

         </td> <!--Конец четвертого столбца-->
     </tr> <!--Конец строки-->   
   </tbody> <!--Конец тела таблицы-->
</table><!--Конец самой таблицы-->
```

Проблема в том что элементы распологаются в упор с друг другом. Каким образом их можно разделить? Допустим на одинаковом растонии на протяжении всего контейнера.

Comment: задать фиксированную ширину и прозрачный border ?

Comment: Deonis. почему то отображает тоже самое только в придачу четвертый элемент ушел под первый

Lucky. Пол сайта перкасило.

Comment: Вообщем мастер пеинт нарисовал и вот загрузил наглядную картинку, на которой видно что мне надо добиться: 
http://s019.radikal.ru/i603/1307/1c/69f416989cfc.jpg

при полном отсутствии кода, все 4 элемента распологаются друг под другом в столбик.

Comment: @Константин645, то что вы пытаетесь сделать, делается элементарным отступом margin. Зачем для этого городить таблицу? И вообще, почитайте хоть одну книгу по CSS перед тем как браться за верстку.

Answer (score 5):

```
 <style>
    ul{
       list-style: none;           
    }
    ul li{
       display: block;
       padding: 0 10px;
       float: left;
       height: 30px;
       border: 1px solid #AAA;
    }
    ul li a{
       display: block;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
    }
 </style>

<ul>
   <li>
      <a>Первый элемент меню</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a>Второй элемент меню</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a>Третий элемент меню</a>
   </li>
       <li>
      <a>Четвертый элемент меню</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Код на [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/enawaw/2/edit).

Comment: Реально лучше на ul и li

Answer (score 1):

Я не сторонник применения таблиц в таких случаях, но если хотите, то [можно сделать так](http://jsfiddle.net/4z2Bc/).